# mono and monodevelop installation

Tags: linux, mono-framework, monodevelop

what is the easiest way to install mono and monodevelop on Ubuntu 8.10 ?

Comment: which version of Mono & Monodevelop?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is:

`sudo apt-get install monodevelop`

in the terminal. This installs MonoDevelop 1.0 on Ubuntu 8.10 (Intrepid).

Answer (score 0):

From http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu

Dependencies are automatically tracked for applications in the archive such as Tomboy and F-Spot. Ubuntu comes with these two applications by default, and therefore comes with Mono installed by default.

To compile your own software, install **mono-devel** on Dapper (6.06 LTS), Jaunty (9.04), Karmic (9.10), or Lucid (10.04 LTS)

To compile your own software, install **mono-2.0-devel** on Hardy (8.04 LTS) or Intrepid (8.10).